# Multiple UIPickerViews

Tags: iphone, ios, dataset, uipickerview, uipicker

I have a dilemma, I have two UIPickerViews which "show" when two distinct views load. I started with one `UIPickerView` and was able to get that up and running by loading the array and all the other `UIPickerView` actions within the ViewController.

I thought it would be as simple as copy/pasting the same methods for the new `UIPickerView`, but just changing the variable names, also within the same `UIViewController`.

Problem is - both `UIPickerView` are showing the same data set in the drop down ? Am I simply missing something obvious here?

*Updated below*

I did that for all four methods below and now that app crashes once the “next” view is loaded?  Does this look right?

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(UIPickerView *)thePickerView 

- (NSInteger)thePickerView:(UIPickerView *)thePickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component

- (NSString *)thePickerView:(UIPickerView *)thePickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component

- (void)thePickerView:(UIPickerView *)thePickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component
```

Comment: yeah the methods look good, your crash is due to something else. Try the debugger! At Run->Debugger. Or post more code.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yeah you are, you have to use the UIPickerView argument to determine WHICH picker view is actually asking for data - since you have set both pickers to the same data source.

```
-(void)numberOfComponentInPickerView:(UIPickerView*)thePickerView {
    if(thePickerView == firstPickerView) {
       // return number of components in first picker    
    } else if(thePickerView == secondPickerView) {    
       // return number of components in second picker    
    } else {
       assert(NO);
    }
}

// repeat for all other delegate / datasource methods
```

Comment: Lol- yea, having a tough time with the formatting - give me one min!

Comment: Updated, thanks I'm wondering if I need to initialize "thePickerView" ? If so - should I associate the UIPickerViews in IB to both "thePickerView" and "secondPickerView" for example?

Comment: No, the thePickerView should be set - it is the picker view which is asking for data - no picker view, no asking for data. Set your picker views as iBOutlets and connect them in the xib. If you are having problems still, you can create two classes - one data source for each picker view, and manually assign them to the picker view instances in the viewDidLoad method.