# Multiple UIPickerViews and datasources

Tags: uipickerview

I have two UIPickerViews that need to go to different datasouces.  The closest answer I could find was this:
[Multiple UIPickerViews](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5545898/multiple-uipickerviews)

But I can't figure out how to do the follwoing:

you can create two classes - one data source for each picker view, and manually assign them to the picker view instances in the viewDidLoad method

Seems easy, but code really use an example.

Answer (score 0):

1. You need to create two classes for your data sources. They obviously should be derived from `NSObject` and implement `UIPickerViewDataSource` protocol.
2. Now you should bound these classes to your `UIPickerView`. The easiest solution is to add instance variables for each data source to `UIViewController`, initialize them and assign to `dataSource` property of `UIPickerView`.

   ```
   @interface MyViewController
   {
       ...
       MyDataSource1 *dataSource1;
       MyDataSource2 *dataSource2;
   }

   ...

   @implementation MyViewController
   - (id) initWith...
   {
       ...
       dataSource1 = [[MyDataSource1 alloc] initWithSmth:smth];
       dataSource2 = [[MyDataSource2 alloc] initWithSmthElse:smthElse];
       return self;
   }

   - (void) viewDidLoad
   {
       ...

       myPickerView1Outlet.dataSource = dataSource1;
       myPickerView2Outlet.dataSource = dataSource2;
   }
   ```